# Tomcat as a client authentication

Tags: authentication, tomcat, client

I have a tomcat server with microservice wars, one WAR that connects with another system, another system requires client authentication, and i have the certificate how to load the certificate with the communication with that system, i tried to use this certificate in the HTTPS encription but failed,
kindly advice i want to load a certififcate if the tomcat will connect with a certain URL,
i mean that the tomcat will be the client not the server,
i know how to make tomcat require client authentication as a server but if there is another system and the tomcat here is the client, how to insert the certificate in tomcat,
the application is java, and the os is linus redhat 7
i tried to inst the certificate to OS level and cacert but same

Comment: We really need more information.  Can you show the code for how you're trying to use the certificate?

Comment: i am trying to do it tomcat level i am not a developer i am a system admin 
Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8446" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="fileto.p12" keystorePass="changeit" keystoreType="PKCS12" truststoreType="PKCS12" SSLCACertificateFile="CAfileto_T.p12" SSLCACertificatePass="changeit"

Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm" Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"

Comment: we handled the client auth from the product itself

Answer (score 0):

I'm at a loss since I'm not a Tomcat person. I use tomcat as a webserver for our Java application and now we are trying to integrate with one of our customers and they require Client Authentication via SSL, so they generated and issued me an SSL certificate to use it in tomcat during the communicating with their system. Unfortunately, this is as far as they support it and cannot give me any direction on how to actually use it.

So what I have is a Java application, a Tomcat app server running 8 on rehat 7, and the .p12 cert from the local CA from customer side.

now i have 2 certificates one for SSL and another as client authentication, how to define the client authentication and attache it with my communication dealing with another system, I tried to use SSLCACertificateFile attribute but no luck,

Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8446" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"
keystoreFile="fileto.p12" keystorePass="changeit" keystoreType="PKCS12"
truststoreType="PKCS12" SSLCACertificateFile="CAfileto_T.p12" SSLCACertificatePass="changeit"

Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm"
Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"